# Change FONT and SIZE of win32gui.DrawText function

Tags: python, pywin32, win32gui

How is it possible to change to font(size) of the `win32gui.DrawText` function from pywin win32gui API?

EDIT: found it out myself. Calling win32ui.GetDeviceCaps to get dpi scale. Then win32gui.LOGFONT() and setting FaceName and Height.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't answer the question in the question. Post an answer instead.